# Converting a decimal integer to a binary string in C

Tags: c, string, binary

Below is the code for my attempt. I have used a function char* dectobin(int ) to do that. I have first converted decimal integer to binary integer (saved in **binary**), then I have converted that binary integer to character array (first in reverse and then in correct order). But I am not getting correct output. Can anyone tell me where the fault is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
char* dectobin(int dec_num);
main()
{
int num;
printf("Enter the integer\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
char* bin_string=dectobin(num);
printf("The binary string representation is %s\n",bin_string);
}
char* dectobin(int dec_num)
{
int remainder;
int base=1; 
int binary=0;
int count=0;
int n;

    while (dec_num > 0)

    {

        remainder = dec_num % 2;

        binary = binary + remainder * base;

        dec_num = dec_num / 2;

        base = base * 10;

    }

 n = log10(binary) + 1;
        int i;
      char* numberArrayreverse = calloc(n, sizeof(char));
        for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i, binary /= 10 )
        {
            numberArrayreverse[i] = binary % 10;
        }
        char* numberArray=calloc(n, sizeof(char));

int j=0;
for(;j<n;j++)
{
numberArray[j]=numberArrayreverse[n-1-j];
}
 //free(numberArrayreverse);
return numberArray;
}
```

Comment: What was the input?  Is `base = base * 10;` or `binary = binary + remainder * base;` overflowing?

Comment: No. Input was small, 23.

Comment: That is not solving the problem

Comment: `calloc(n, sizeof(char));` is also 1 too small for a _string_ of `n` digits.

Comment: @chux: agreed, but it was still working.

Comment: "... it was still working" is due to _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @chux: you are right

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numberArrayreverse` is not correct, need to convert integer to char.

```
numberArrayreverse[i] = binary % 10 + '0';
```